# How to install module Open Cart without extention installer mode?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I try to install module in Open Cart using Estention Installer. But server doeest support FTP function `bind` therefore I can not use this way.

How can I install module without extention installer [this module](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info)?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the ftp and use native php functions to move files around.  I wrote this mod to solve that exact problem:

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=24945